# Applying OpengGL Shader in Qt Thread

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a problem with adding Shaders to an OpenGL Window while in a Thread.

The code is here: https://github.com/odie42/qtopengl

It seems to load the shaders etc, but doesn't update the buffer or something. I can't figure out why the shader/geometry isn't displayed.

// EDIT

I actually found a solution. I'll upload the working code if anyone is interested.

Comment: Can you please try to narrow down the relevant code. You might get more response if people do not need to read through reams and reams of code.

Comment: The problem is, i dont know which code is exactly relevant. I don't know if applying the shader/creating the geometries is the problem or if there's a problem within the thread doing this

Comment: General advice is to keep all OpenGL functionality in 1 thread. Sharing contexts between threads is looking for trouble.

Comment: i just create the context in the main thread and move all handling to my thread.

Comment: No can do. All OpenGL calls have a specific implicit thread local context. Therefore contexts cannot be shared across threads without being really clever. For that reason, you may only have 1 OpenGL thread.

Comment: but i can only create new widgets (therefore QGLContext) in the GUI Thread (aka the main thread)

Comment: The GUI thread is exactly where your openGL code should live. You can use QTimer at 60fps (or possible something better) to trigger your animation callbacks.

Comment: Well i got the idea and i'll test it. thank you!

Comment: But what if the main thread is occupied with loading other GUI Elements? will the timer still be called?

Comment: The timer may be triggered late so you will have to keep track of elapsed time between frames to advance the animation by the correct amount. In any event, if you are having long running operations in the gui thread you are doing something wrong and probably need to split them up with callbacks.

Comment: The Problem is that the project doesn't use the UI files. It generates the GUI based on .ini files. If a module is set to load, then the GUI is generated at the startup of the program (where the OpenGL logo should appear). I tried the method with a QBasicTimer but the animation stops once the gui thread is occupied with loading the GUI objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to 'move' the opengl context, as described here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_and_multithreading

Comment: I actually do this in  LogoWidget::startRendering(), context()->moveToThread(&thread);

Comment: Are you sure your problem is thread related, does it work if the code run only on a single thread ?

Comment: yes, this is the example from Qt Creator (Cube OpenGL ES 2.0 example). i just moved the relevant calls into a thread.

Comment: It seem you don't set bDoRendering to true.

Comment: it was initialized with true. even if i set it to "true" in the Constructor of the Thread i dont see the geometry (cube).